# Waiting on the following files on renderFiles

Tags: node.js, docpad

I'm using [DocPad](http://docpad.org/) (NodeJS) and I have 100 pages ( + or -).

When running the command `docpad run` I get the following message:

```
Waiting on The Following files on renderFiles:
...lists some files that should be rendered but were not
```

**Some can help me?**

- node --version v0.10.29
- docpad --version v6.69.0 (local installation: /home/...bla bla bla
- Plugins: cleanurls, eco, livereload, marked, pygments
- Environment: development

Comment: npm --version 2.0.0-beta

Comment: [docpad-debug.log](https://gist.github.com/flaviomicheletti/cea658c1b4ce20335e21)

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Not yet!  But, I gave up DocPad.